# moving to anther html page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make the button run the function which I made, so that I can move to another html.

```js
    function imacne(){
      if (maxClassName == "imflammary"){
        location.href="carepage2.html";
      }
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="imacne()" id="gotoseesolution">go see solution</button>
```

Comment: And what's wrong with that?

Comment: can you elaborate more because this seems already working or you can try window.location.href="carepage2.html"

Comment: <div><button type="button" onclick="imacne()" id="gotoseesolution">goseethesolution</button></div>

Comment: i didn't uploaded this sry

Comment: i cannot move to the another html

Comment: what's your **maxClassName**?

Comment: its a string that is randomly assigned

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There's no obvious reason (beyond the definition of `maxClassName` being missing from your example code) why this wouldn't work. You need to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Also you should probably just use a link and not a button.

Answer (score -1):

`location.replace("carepage2.html")` works fine.

Comment: i tried but it also didn't work